# Aurora Postgresql's insert statements aren't recognizing existing key IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

After migrating from RDS Postgresql to RDS Aurora PostgreSQL, I am having an issue to where new inserts are trying to start from key ID 2 instead of the last record.

In my rails app, here's what I'm seeing when I try to create a new record:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "global_options_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
):

app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

Not sure why this would be the case. To set up Aurora PSQL in Rails, I followed this tutorial: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html. It seems like everything is working fine (auto switching between reader/writer instances, etc.).

With the migration, I specifically used the AWS Schema Conversion Tool (SCT), followed by a migration with the Database Migration Service.

Is this error caused by something that was done incorrectly in the migration process or do I need to some post-migration processes to have this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a case of when you migrated old data, but not with `INSERT` and your sequences are still on the initial values.

Use [sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) to check what is the current value with `lastval()`, and set it to `max(id)` with `setval()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table_name|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)
end
```